# java web applets and e-mail

Tags: java, html, email, applet

I'm working on a project where the idea is to estimate a price and send all via e-mail so that the person can then be contacted.

I have created an applet that works exactly how I want it to. It gets the required information and sends it via e-mail. The problem is that when I start the application in a browser the e-mail never gets sent.

I cannot seem to get my head around what I am missing. I have the .java file and the .class file, I also have a simple .html file to start the code in the web page

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<body>
<applet code=priceCalculator.Calculator1.class archive="javax.mail-1.5.5.jar" width="450" height="400" >
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

What else am I missing? Do I need another file, or am I missing code from the html file?

Comment: Applets run inside a sandbox and have issues creating netwprk connections anywhere (except back to the server they're loaded from). You might consider client/server or webapp or need to sign your applet and request permissions

Comment: To provide helpful feedback we will also need to see your Java code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the program, i cant seem to get it onto here, so i had to upload it through dropbox :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/30uvgvzm9hlhsgi/WEBCALC.txt?dl=0
if it isnt possible to do it this way, what would be the best way to go??

Turns out everybody was correct, newbie stubborness wasted lots of hours of my time!! Advice to newbies, listen to the experts!!

Answer (score 0):

As been said in the comments Applets can only open network connections to the host from where they were downloaded. So unless the mail server is running on the same host you are not going to be able send the mail.

You can read the [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) to see the limitations